# Insert If Table Exists in Databricks or Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am writing in a Databricks notebook where I need to say something like:

```
%sql

IF EXISTS myTable INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE myTable SELECT * FROM somethingElse
```

I know that the `INSERT OVERWRITE` clause works, but I'm not sure how to get the `IF EXISTS` to work without breaking out of pure SQL code and using python (which would make the script messier).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no DDL named "IF EXISTS" supported in Databricks.

You have to use command called "Drop Table":

Drop a table and delete the directory associated with the table from the file system if this is not an EXTERNAL table. If the table to drop does not exist, an exception is thrown.

**IF EXISTS**

If the table does not exist, nothing happens.

```
DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name
```

**Example:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS diamonds;

CREATE TABLE diamonds USING CSV OPTIONS (path "/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv", header "true")
```

**Reference:** [SQL Language Manual](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/index.html#sql-language-manual)   This is a complete list of Data Definition Language (DDL) and Data Manipulation Language (DML) constructs supported in Databricks.

Hope this helps.